# PULP_CBC_CMD doesn't exit on KeyboardInterrupt...is there a better way?

Tags: python, pulp

I have a python application that is packaged in PyPI that uses PuLP for optimization. I usually run it on Ubuntu WSL. Sometimes the optimization clearly won't finish and I have to kill it. When I do that, if the PULP_CBC_CMD solver is being used, the solver will continue to run and I have to manually kill it. This doesn't happen when I run it in Windows. So I did this (haven't released this to the repository yet):

```
try:
    solver = pu.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=msg)
    status = lp_prob.solve(solver)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    import os
    if os.name == "posix":
        import psutil
        pids = psutil.pids()
        for pid in pids:
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            if p.name() == "cbc":
                p.terminate()
                p.kill()                    
                sys.exit(1)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

This works. However, I don't really want to release a package that requires psutil just to kill the CBC solver on KeyboardInterrupt, and I don't want to kill it this way (by looking for anything named "cbc") even if I do. Is there a better way to ensure the solver dies when the program dies?

Since asking this, I found a more robust method that works in both WSL and Windows without any errors, but it still uses psutil. So I'm leaving this up to see if anyone knows a pulp-specific way to ensure termination.

```
try:
    solver = pu.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=msg)
    status = lp_prob.solve(solver)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    import psutil
    current_process = psutil.Process()
    children = current_process.children(recursive=True)
    for child in children:
        child_process = psutil.Process(child.pid)
        child_process.terminate()
        child_process.kill()
    exit(1)
```